# Es posible adherir al menú de cualquier documento un script para tener la opción de convertir el documento a PDF

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-apps-script-menu

Con el siguiente script convierto a PDF un documento especifico, el script se adhiere al menú al abrir el documento. Soy nuevo en la programación de scripts y no se si es posible hacer que este u otro script se pudiera adherir al menú al abrir cualquier documento para tener la opción de convertirlo a PDF. De antemano gracias por su tiempo.

```
function onOpenDocument()
{
    var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('PDF')
              .addItem('Convertir a PDF', 'PDF')
              .addToUi();
}

function PDF()
{
    var file = null;
    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getName());

    if ( files.hasNext() )
    {
        file = files.next();
    }
    var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(file.getAs('application/pdf'));
}
```

Comment: ¿Viste mi respuesta? ¿Te fue útil?

Answer (score 1):

Es posible agregar un menú a todos los documentos mediante  un complemento. Los detalles en

[Develop Add-ons for Google Sheets, Docs, Slides, and Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/)